# Change default color theme in ActionBarDrawerToggle

Tags: android, android-theme

I am applying a style in my Android app where the main colour is the orange. So I would like to set up a theme where the main colour is orange instead of the blue one in Holo theme. Is there a way to change globally the theme colours?

For example, I would like to change the drawable which is applied while pressing the ActionBarDrawerToggle. How could I change that drawable? And the one with the caret pressed to go to a parent activity?

[image: eenter image description here]

I am developing an Android app for Level 10 API and using Support Library v7.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a tool such as [Android Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/) to change the coloring of the action bar and the accent color used for touch highlighting (although note the Kitkat styling is light gray touch highlighting rather than colored highlighting).

Similarly, for the Navigation Drawer icon itself you can use the [Navigation Drawer Indicator Generator](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-nav-drawer-indicator.html) to colorize the drawer itself, although generally you should consider coloring the Action Bar with your primary color and using the default holo light/dark for icons.